# How to get better performance in Desktop Streaming over TCP?

Tags: c#, xamarin, tcp, bitmap, compression

I am working on a software solution to stream a Windows Desktop to a Xamarin application, using TCP.
It works, but I cannot manage to get better framerate.

Here's how I do :

The client, a Xamarin app, listens on a Tcp socket. The server (C# console app) connects to it, captures the Desktop and sends the image. Then, the app show it as an `Image`.

When sending a bitmap, the server starts sending its size, on a 4 bytes array. The client first listens 4 bytes, then the requested size.

**DesktopRecorder.cs** (Server side)

```
private void CaptureScreen()
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(SIZE.Width, SIZE.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, SIZE, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    CaptureReady(BitmapToArray(bitmap));
}

private byte[] BitmapToArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**TcpNetworker.cs** (Server side, connecting in TCP):

```
public override void SendData(byte[] data)
{
    if (Tcp.Connected)
    {
        int size = data.Length;
        var sizeArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            sizeArray.Reverse();

        Console.WriteLine($"Sending {size} o.");

        Write(sizeArray);

        Stream.Flush();

        Write(data);
    }

    void Write(byte[] b)
    {
        Stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs** (Client side, Xamarin):

```
private void Accept()
{
    try
    {
        var client = Tcp.AcceptTcpClient();

        Console.WriteLine("---------------- Client Connected ----------------");

        Stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] sizeArray;
        byte[] dataArray;

        while (client.Connected)
        {
            sizeArray = new byte[4];
            Stream.Read(sizeArray, 0, 4);

            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                sizeArray.Reverse();

            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeArray, 0);

            Console.WriteLine($"Size: {size}");

            dataArray = new byte[size];
            Stream.Read(dataArray, 0, size);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ImageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MemoryStream(dataArray)));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message} {Environment.NewLine} {e.StackTrace}");
    }

    Accept();
}
```

**MainWindow.cs** (Page's code behind):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var model = new MainWindowViewModel();
    model.ImageReceived += Model_ImageReceived;
}

private void Model_ImageReceived(object sender, System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    //var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imageSource.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    imageSource.EndInit();
    
    MainImage.Source = imageSource;

    memoryStream.Dispose();
}
```

The `CaptureScreen()` method of **DesktopRecorder** is called on a given framerate. It works *fine* at 10 FPS, but when increasing this framerate, I get trouble in the client, the app cannot manage to find the correct size. After receiving some images, the 4 bytes read doesn't contain the size. It is like an offset has been added, and the server/client unsychronize.

So, I am asking 2 things :

- How can I keep a synchronization between the server and client after sending many TCP packets, since I need to keep 4 bytes for the size ? I don't feel using a fixed size of bitmap or something like that.
- Currently, I am encoding the bitmap into a PNG image, which can be handled natively by Xamarin. Is there a better way to compress my image and sends it faster, even there is a loss in quality ? I already did that kind of things between a C server and an Angular app, and I had to encode it in PNG and Base64. Can I do the same ?

P.S : I know I can manage to get better performance using UDP, but for some reasons, I have to keep with TCP :/.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you need to add some delimiter in your data so that WHEN you get out of sync you can look for the next delimiter to get you back in sync

Comment: I think I understand, but it forces me to look into the whole buffer, and also the delimiter may be splitted into 2 paquets, no ?

Comment: Yes.  Streaming is hard.